# Convert array into cow

Tags: rust

I'm trying to pass an array to a function but getting the following error:

```
186 |     mqtt_client.publish(
    |                 ------- required by a bound introduced by this call
...
190 |             buffer,
    |             ^^^^^^ the trait `From<[u8; 80]>` is not implemented for `Cow<'_, [u8]>`
```

The array was created by the following line and the content of it is mofidied before calling `publish()`.

`let mut buffer: [cty::uint8_t; 80] = [0; 80];`

The function is defined as:

```
    fn publish<'a, V>(
        &'a mut self,
        payload: V,
    ) -> Result<client::MessageId, Self::Error>
    where
        V: Into<Cow<'a, [u8]>>,
```

Having read about [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) and [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) I'm still at a loss how to go about solving this issue.

Comment: Not an answer because I'm too weak on Rust for this to be more than a doc-based guess, but maybe: `mqtt_client.publish(Cow::From(&buffer[..]))` so it takes a slice and uses that?

Comment: Just a `mqtt_client.publish(&buffer[..])` is enough.

Comment: @ShadowRanger if you could post the same solution as an anwer I would accept it as the correct asnwer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cow` doesn't recognize your specific array type, but it works with arbitrary slices, which arrays convert to trivially. Just change:

```
mqtt_client.publish(
        buffer,
```

to:

```
mqtt_client.publish(
        Cow::from(&buffer[..]), // Explicit conversion
```

or:

```
mqtt_client.publish(
        &buffer[..],            // Implicit conversion
```

so `Cow` is working with a recognized type.